# MomentJS - parse utc string where its BST locally

Tags: momentjs

Currently i'm using moment to format dates. Its currently BST locally so UTC offset is + 1 hour.

```
moment('2017-09-15T13:01:35+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
// "2017-09-15 13:01"
```

What I don't understand is the offset is +0100 so shouldn't this mean that its utc plus one hour (BST), so when its formatted locally it should be 2017-09-15 14:01?

Comment: Okay just looked through moment's documentation and it seems the time includes the offset. So

moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00

So to get UTC I need to minus the offset on the displayed time. Which makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input string is `2017-09-15T13:01:35+0100`.  This is the ISO-8601 format.

In this format, the offset *describes* how the time given is offset from UTC.  In other words, read this as `"At 13:01:35 local time on September 15th 2017, the local time was 1 hour ahead of UTC."`

Thus, to derive the UTC time, *subtract* the offset.  The UTC time was `2017-09-15T12:01:35Z`.

Also, I'd encourage you to use either the full "Extended Format", which has a `:` in the offset (`2017-09-15T13:01:35+01:00`), or use the "Basic Format" which eliminates *all* `:` and `-` characters (`20170915T130135+0100`).  Otherwise, you're mixing the two forms, which is non-compliant and may not be understood by all parsers.